# "Increment" file name in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have some code in Qt which creates a CSV file, if the file does not  exist I create one like this...

```
QString base = Settings::get().logDirectory(); //get directory from settings
QString path = QString("%1/results.csv").arg(base);
```

If results.csv already exists, how can I generate a new file called for example results1.csv, results2.csv and keep "incrementing" it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following:

```
QString base = Settings::get().logDirectory(); //get directory from settings
QString path = QString( "%1/results.csv" ).arg( base );
int idx = 1;
while ( QFile::exists( path ) ) {
    path = QString( "%1/results%2.csv" ).arg( base ).arg( idx++ );
}

// Create a file with 'path'
[..]
```